# Chef nagios cookbook doesn't install check_nrpe on server

Tags: chef, nagios

I'm trying to build an updated monitoring server, using the current version of the Chef nagios cookbook (3.1). It installs nagios-3.4.3 from source on my Ubuntu VM.

But I don't find any evidence of the check_nrpe command on the server, so all of my remote checks fail with "(Return code of 127 is out of bounds - plugin may be missing)".

I don't find anything in the recipe documentation or the source code for the cookbook that would include the check_nrpe plugin.

Anyone have a tip for me?

Comment: I'm thinking it might have to do with installing nagios from source, rather than packages. Not sure yet.

Answer (score 1):

The source install for nagios does not install the nrpe plugin.

I've written an update to do the source install, and I'll submit a patch to the cookbook.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I guess the cookbook has changed since last I looked.  You can't use the `nagios::client_package` recipe?  You probably will need to change the `install_method` attribute, as the `nagios::client` includes either package or source install recipes.  Here's the relevant line from `nagios::client`:

```
include_recipe "nagios::client_#{node['nagios']['client']['install_method']}"
```

where the `client_package` recipe just does this:

```
%w{
  nagios-nrpe-server
  nagios-plugins
  nagios-plugins-basic
  nagios-plugins-standard
}.each do |pkg|
  package pkg
end
```

which will install the `nagios-nrpe-server` Ubuntu package as well as the standard plugins.

Comment: Yep, that is indeed the thing. Apparently the default nagios install method for Ubuntu 10 is from source. I'm okay with that. I just completed a patch that will do the source install for nrpe alongside the nagios server, so I've solved the problem.